# Retaining state of iframe pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent page that contains iframe , the parent page doesnt have anything except the iframe and a widget that needs to be there as the user navigates the website.

What I want to do is: Whenever the iframe changes to a new location, I want the parent page to change the address so it can be bookmarked.

Also, how  the links inside iframe be written ?

I've tried `History.js` plugin that uses HTML5 state, but I don't know how to apply it to my use case. It just shows  ajax examples.

Comment: are parent and child on the same domain?

Comment: yes, they are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you get rid of the iframe all together? They aren't very popular, and this exact question is being asked quite alot and also ignored a lot.

Found this on page 2 f googling 'bookmark site inside iframe'

http://matthewmanela.com/blog/making-linking-between-anchors-in-an-iframe-work-in-firefox-11-and-above/